# Determine whether the function is a linear transformation between vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Problem: $T:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$, $T(x) = -2x$

I approached this problem trying to find counter examples to show that one of the properties of linear transformations fails to hold. I was unable to find any examples so I attempted to prove it as a whole. I'm unsure about my proof for scalar multiplication. Any advice or further explanations on how to improve my answer would be greatly appreciated.

T(x+y) = -2(x + y) = -2(x) + (-2(y)) = T(x) + T(y)

Ex: Let x = 1 and y = 2, then

T(x + y) = T(3) = -2(3) = -6 = -2(1) + (-2(2)) = T(x) + T(y), which is linear.

T(cu) = -2(cu) = c * -2(u) = cT(u)

Ex: Let c = 2 and u = 3

T(cu) = T(6) = -2(6) = -12 = 2T(3) = 2(-6) = cT(u)

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Maybe you should prove $T(x) = ax + b$ instead.